# Sending notification to all logged users in javafx

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to make a multi user application using `javafx` (i.e many users can be using the application sharing a common data base).

What I want is when a user adds in data in a table in db, admin user should be notified immediately.

Currently, he has to refresh the table to see the updated changes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use socket-server communication for real time notification.
See here for examples: http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_networking.htm